# How can I shuffle a specific range of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

In Java, I know that to shuffle an ArrayList, the method Collections.shuffle() exists, however this shuffles the entire list.

How can I write a method (or, can someone write it and show me it?) such as the following:

```
private ArrayList<AnObject> list;

/**
 * Shuffles the concents of the array list in the range [start, end], and 
 * does not do anything to the other indicies of the list.
 */
public void shuffleArrayListInTheRange(int start, int end)
```

Comment: Rather amazing to see four answers saying almost the same thing. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [`List.subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) and [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), like this:

```
Collections.shuffle(list.subList(start, end));
```

(Note that the second index to `subList` **exclusive**, so use `end+1` if you want to include `end` index in the shuffle.)

Since `List.subList` returns *a view* of the list, changes made (by the shuffle method) to the sub list, will also affect the original list.

Answer (score 8):

Yes - use [List.sublist(start, end)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) and [Collections.shuffle()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) that, ie:

```
Collections.shuffle(list.sublist(start, end));
```

`sublist` returns a *view* of the list, so when you shuffle it, you shuffle the actual list but only between start and end

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.shuffle(list.subList(start, end+1));
```

Note the +1, because the end index of `subList()` is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
public void shuffleArrayListInTheRange(int start, int end) {
    Collections.shuffle(list.subList(start, end));
}
```